# Apache2 - Subdomain to port -> forwarding

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain, portforwarding, dyndns

Okay, I'm at a certain point where I feel a huge amount of stupidity on myself because of reading hundreds of manual and instruction pages and still not getting it. I hope you can help me!

I have a server running Ubuntu Server. On the server I'm running ddclient for updating my IP with dyn.com. There I have a domain "rasterkomplex.net" which points to the updated IP. Easy.

There is also a camera connected to the server which runs it's own webserver @ port 3360.

When I'm now entering: rasterkomplex.net:3360 - voilà.
But now comes 2 minecraft server running simultaneously on 5001 and 5002. For every mc-server, there's the dynmap-plugins which runs also a webserver on different port. And then a webstorage on... you get it? I don't want to remember like 8 or more ports, just for accessing the related service.

What I want to accomplish:

```
cam.rasterwerks.net -> internal to 127.0.0.1:3360
mc1.rasterwerks.net -> internal to 127.0.0.1:5001
mc2.rasterwerks.net -> internal to 127.0.0.2:5002
etc. etc. etc.
```

I read a lot about VHosts, ProxyPass etc. But I'm not able to manage it getting work.

Can you give me a direction how to accomplish this? If it has to do with VHosts, maybe a sample?

Thank you very very much for your time!

Regards,

Elias.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `apache` on one hand with `ProxyPass` of `mod_proxy` redirecting you here or there, or, what you also can do is install `haproxy`. Then, based on the Host in the URL that's being requested pass the request to one or another web storage.

An example config of `haproxy` doing exactly that would be:

```
frontend public
bind        X.X.X.X:80
mode        http
log         global
option      httplog
option      dontlognull
option      httpclose
maxconn     8000
clitimeout  90000

reqisetbe   ^Host:\ .*hudson    hudson

backend hudson
    mode            http
    balance         roundrobin
    contimeout      120000
    srvtimeout      120000
    redispatch
    retries         5
    server          internal.host.com Y.Y.Y.Y:8080 check inter 1000
```

So in this example, `haproxy` is bound to port 80 and when URL that's requested contains `*.hudson`, it gets redirected to an `internal.host.com` with IP of `Y.Y.Y.Y` to port `8080`.

Now, for the `apache` based solution.

You can define multiple VHosts, with different names, each of them containing the following.

To do name-based vhosting, your apache config should contain:

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Then, the vhost itself, should be:

```
<Virtualhost *>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/somewhere"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAdmin support@mycompany.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia full

  <proxy>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </proxy>

  ProxyPass        /  http://somehost:1234/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://somehost:1234/
</Virtualhost>
```

Feel free to choose whatever solution seems more viable to you.

Comment: I went with the VHost solution and it worked mostly like a charm - except for the tries where the request doesn't comes from port 80, like when I try to use ssh, games or rtsp. But I guess that is because apache2 is just a webserver?

How else could that be accomplished? With this haproxy thing?

Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, apache is just the webserver. haproxy, on the other hand is a TCP-capable loadbalancer of sorts.